# Does Amazon MWS Throtlling means you can update 15 records or execute 15 update API calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I posted this question on MWS forum but, didn't get an answer. So, I'm posting this here hoping for an answer.
Here goes:

Hi,
I'm an absolute newbie in to MWS and I'm trying to understand the throttling impact on my design.

Taking an example of Submit Feed, it says that I can submit 15 *requests* at a time before throttling applies. 
That's clear enough except for what a *request* means? On the face of it, it would mean one MWS API call: Which means I can send 15 AmazonEnvelopes before I run in to throttling. Correct?

Now say I need to update 25 products. What I need is to send 25 *Messages*. The XSD for AmazonEnvelope specifies maxoccurs=unbounded. Which means I can put all the 25 messages in one envelope and have it count as one *request*. Isn't that the case?
So, I'm should only consider (from the docs):
"One good practice is to submit feeds with a size limit of 30,000
records/items or submit feeds"
If I'm doing nothing else, I can "potentially" update 30,000*15 items without throttling.
Is this correct?

Thanks in advance for any answers you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means 15 requests.  The request can include a large number of products.  Using the Flat File for inventory loading, using c#, see below.

```
SubmitFeedRequest req = new SubmitFeedRequest();

    req.ContentMD5 = MarketplaceWebServiceClient.CalculateContentMD5(feedContent);
    feedContent.Position = 0;
    req.FeedContent = feedContent;
    req.FeedType = "_POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA_";
    req.PurgeAndReplace = false;
    req.Marketplace = MarketPlaceId;
    req.Merchant = MerchantId;

    return Service.SubmitFeed(req);
```

The flat file feeds are kind of hard to find, I found it by going to the following URL while logged into my sellercentral account.

You then need the flat file feed specifications to send the flat file in the correct format to the MWS. That can be found after you're logged into your seller central account:

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html/ref=ag_13461_cont_help?ie=UTF8&itemID=13461&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was hoping to be the answer. However, I'm going to use XML rather than flat files (for project specific reasons). I don't think it would matter whether it's flat or xml... Or does it?

Comment: When I worked on it, a year ago, I was required to apply to amazon to use XML, I didn't bother with that so used flat file instead.  I would prefer to use XML but seemed like an unnecessary hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Search this PDF for "throttle" and you'll likely find the answer: [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSDeveloperGuide.*V159025213*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSDeveloperGuide._V159025213_.pdf)

It's sounding as though you would get throttled at 15 requests; waiting between requests releases some back to you.  It's rather confusing at best.

Comment: Yup, that's one of the docs I've read. What I don't get is does it limit me in the number of times I can call the API, or limit the actual number records I can work with. Looks like the former to me, if not that seems horribly limiting

Comment: Maybe newer documentation (don't need to search a PDF) -- see [SubmitFeed docs](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_ES/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html) which links to the [Throttling Explanation](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_ES/dev_guide/DG_Throttling.html):  The SubmitFeed operation has a maximum **request quota** of 15 and a restore rate of one request every two minutes, where one 'request' is changing one or many records.